# How to configure SSRS report to access Oracle database on SQL Server machine where Report Server is installed?

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I am sure that someone was successful to deployed SSRS report on the server where
SSRS is configured to access Oracle database.
I developed report on my machine where I have Visual Studio 2017, 
ODTwithODAC122011 64-bit; 32-bit ODT withODAC122011. I connect to Oracle database and can run report.
After i deployed this report on Windows Server  2016. i got an error "An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
 An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ORACLE' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsDataExtensionNotFound".
I tried to complete the same ODAC install as on my machine.
1)Installed ODTwithODAC122011 64-bit - configured TNS name.
but with step 
2) i tried to install 32-bit ODT - I received error that i need to install Visual studio to proceed with installation.
Do i really need VS on the server? What is the possible solution you can share?
thank you --Angelika--

Answer (score 0):

with only the Oracla.DataAccess library should be enough, on the root of the service. Be aware the versions be the same as indicated in the project references